# Method to get service ID in qt c++

Tags: c++, database, qt, methods, remote-access

I am currently developing a user login in Qt using c++ to access a remote oracle database. It has line edits to get username,password, IP address, port number and service ID. I found methods to extract username, password, IP address and port number. But I could not find a method to extract service ID.

my code is as follows

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    mydb.setHostName (ui->ip->text()); //ip address
    mydb.setDatabaseName ("My database");
    mydb.setUserName (ui->uname->text());
    mydb.setPassword (ui->pword->text());
    mydb.setPort(ui->Port->text());
}
```

What is the method that I can use to extract the service id?

Comment: QSQLITE or ORACLE?

Comment: @eyllanesc oracle! I think even we use both it will work right?

Comment: QSQLite only needs setDatabaseName().

Comment: @eyllanesc Ah okay thanx! If I use an oracle driver what is the method I should use to extract service ID?

Comment: Have you tried connecting without that parameter?

Comment: When I connected to that type of database I have not used that parameter.

Comment: @eyllanesc  But even in oracle sql developer tool  we have to give service id right? if we won't to connect to a remote database?

Comment: see this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/53051/solved-connect-oracle-database-from-qt-creator/6

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanx! In the forum post  databasename=XE means the service id or just a name?